# How to use `cplexAPI` to solve quadratic programs/quadratically constrained linear programs?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, quadratic-programming, r

I am trying to use `cplexAPI` to solve quadratic programs or quadratically constrained linear program.

While it seems to be pretty straightforward to use `cplexAPI` to solve linear programs (with the vignette at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cplexAPI/vignettes/cplexAPI.pdf), it seems that using `cplexAPI` to solve quadratic programs or linear programs with a quadratic constraint is much more difficult. I tried to look over the package documentation, but I have no clue on how to do so.

Therefore, may I know how to use `cplexAPI` to solve quadratic programs or linear programs, or if there is any code samples for these two tasks?

In addition, the package `Rcplex` seems to be pretty similar, but its last update is already more than 5 years ago. So it would be really nice to know how the above two tasks can be done using `cplexAPI` in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This document available on link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/Rcplex.pdf for RCplex might be helpful for you. Page 7 & 8 has an example of QCP.

Comment: I know this can be done in `Rcplex`, but I would like to learn about how they can be done in `cplexAPI` because `Rcplex` has not been updated for more than 5 years. Thanks!

Comment: same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69172344/how-to-use-cplexapi-to-solve-quadratic-programs-linear-programs-with-quadratic/69193704#69193704

Comment: Hmmm yes because another user kindly suggested me to post in OR StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

with cplexAPI you may use [addQConstrCPLEX](https://rdrr.io/cran/cplexAPI/man/addQConstrCPLEX.html) to add quadratic constraints